# twitter bootstrap tabs access via external link

Tags: javascript, tabs, twitter-bootstrap

I've set up twitter bootstrap on a Rails 3.0 app, and have a page (edit.html.haml) with three tabs. Here is my code (i'm using haml):

```
.tabbable
    %ul.nav.nav-tabs
      %li.active
        %a{"data-toggle" => "tab", :href => "#1"} 
          %i.icon-pencil
          Edit Profile
      %li
        %a{"data-toggle" => "tab", :href => "#2"} 
          %i.icon-lock
          Privacy Preferences
      %li
        %a{"data-toggle" => "tab", :href => "#3"} 
          %i.icon-cogs
          Site Preferences
    .well-two  
      .tab-content
        #1.tab-pane.active
          %p ...
        #2.tab-pane
          %p ...
        #3.tab-pane
          %p ...
```

The tabs are working fine when I'm on the edit page (I can move between them and they respond as they should); however, let's say I'm on the show page (show.html.haml) and have a button that says: Click here to Change your Privacy Settings (ie: go to the second tab on the edit page)... what code is necessary to link to the Privacy Setting (#2) content?

I have the following code:

```
=link_to "#{raw('<i class="icon-plus-sign icon-large"></i>')} Privacy Settings".html_safe, edit_path(current_profile, :anchor => "2")
```

But it is not working... it takes me to the edit page, but does not load the Privacy Setting data (ie the data under #2).

Note: even when I'm on the edit page, and change my URL from: http://localhost:3000/users/1/edit to http://localhost:3000/users/1/edit#2, it does not take me to the second tab.

Am I missing any additional JS? Your help would be extremely appreciated. Also, your answers don't have to be in Haml or Rails compliant... I can re-write them, I am just seeking some guidance and advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

this code seemed to fix the problem:

```
:javascript
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').click()
  });
```